# Tab width increases on content size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was working with a multlevel megamenu. Trying to add multiple lists inside a tab. But when the content increases, the tab size also increases. And hence other tabs go down.How to make it constant width so that other tabs can come along horizontally.

[image]

Html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">       
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Sample2<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="container" >
              <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1primary" data-toggle="tab" data-item="#div2">Sample2.1</a>
                    <div id="div2" style="display: none" class="root_list">
                    <ul>
                    <li>Sample2.1.1
                    </li>
                    <li>Sample2.1.2
                    </li>
                    </ul>

           <ul>
                    <li>Sample2.1.1
                    </li>
                    <li>Sample2.1.2
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                      <ul>
                    <li>Sample2.1.1
                    </li>
                    <li>Sample2.1.2
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                      </div>
                  </li>

                  <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab" data-item="#div1">Sample2.2</a>

                    <div id="div1" style="display: none">
                   <ul>
                    <li>Sample2.2.1
                    </li>
                    <li>Sample2.2.2
                    </li>
                      </ul></div>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#tab3primary" data-toggle="tab">Sample2.3</a></li>
                </ul>       


              </div>
            </div>


          </ul>
        </li>





      </ul>

    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS and script in the demo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYJEGw

Comment: Can't you just set a fixed width like `250px` to the parent of the tab element (Which seems to be `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` here)?

Comment: Thats not working..